# How apply one sidebar for several pages in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I have created one website by WordPress. I have one sidebar that I want apply to several pages. I read a lot of tutorials but I could not find any solutions?  How can I do this??

Comment: What theme are you using, please?

Comment: So it's Avada premium theme: https://theme-fusion.com/avada-doc/widgets/assigning-widget-sections-to-sidebars/ … Read the docs  :)

Comment: In this doc there is Global sidebar concept, and I can apply one sidebar  for all my pages, but I need to make group for my pages. For example one sidebar for first group of pages and another sidebar for second group.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

Modify your theme - create custom page template and register new sidebar. It's pretty well documented on WordPress.org

- [Page templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/)
- [Sidebars](https://codex.wordpress.org/Sidebars)

### Solution 2

If you are not WP developer, this is simper and more user friendly solution for you.

1. Install [Widget Logic](https://codex.wordpress.org/Sidebars) plugin.
2. Add widgets to sidebar via WordPress administration.
3. Click on widget and specify conditions. For example you can restrict displaying of widget for pages in specific category: **is_category(array(5,9,10,11))**

For more condition examples read Widget Logic - [Other notes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/other_notes/) section

Answer (score 0):

If you are using avada theme you don't need to do anything, there is already option available for selecting sidebar on any page, so you can choose one sidebar for many page you wish.
If you didn't find Fusion Page Options in edit page screen than you have check your screen options.